# Subsetting rows in R

Tags: r, subset, sqldf

I have a huge data set in the following format:

```
 ID       Interaction         Interaction_number
  1         abc                    1
  1         xyz                    2
  1         pqr                    3
  1         ced                    0
  2         ab                     0
  2         efg                    1
  3         asdf                   2
  3         fgh                    3
  3         abc                    0
  4         sql                    1
  4         ghj                    2
  5         poi                    2
  6         pqr                    1
```

Now I want to extract all the ID data where there is interaction_number as 0. for eg:

```
 ID       Interaction         Interaction_number
  1         abc                    1
  1         xyz                    2
  1         pqr                    3
  1         ced                    0
  2         ab                     0
  2         efg                    1
  3         asdf                   2
  3         fgh                    3
  3         abc                    0
```

Its a huge dataset. I need to extract it using R.

I tried using the sqldf function.

```
x<-sqldf("select * from data where data$ID in (select data$ID from data where data$Interaction_number ==0)")
```

But the function didnt work. I was looking to add a flagging column ( 1 for all IDs where there is interaction_number 0) and then subset those rows. But I cant figure out exactly how to do.
Can we create the data frame of the ID's and then using that data frame, we can use subset to get all the rows?

Please help.
Thank You

Comment: There is no `Interaction` equal to 0 in your example. Do you mean `Interaction_number`. If so, your output is unclear.

Comment: yeah sorry I meant Interaction_number

Comment: I basically want all the rows for the respective IDs where there has been a 0 Interaction_number

Comment: But still, your expected output is incorrect, right?

Comment: Check the sqldf function, it will give you the basic output I need.

Comment: It's actually quite simple subsetting in base R: `df[df$ID %in% df$ID[df$Interaction_number == 0],]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `data.table` package. Then you could obtain your result. Say your data is in `data.frame` `df`. Then

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key = 'ID')
tmp <- dt[, list(condition = any(Interaction_number == 0)), by = ID]
res <- dt[tmp[condition == TRUE, list(ID)]]
```

Comment: I believe that `df[ID %in% df[Interaction_number == 0, ID]]` would be more efficient than the by-group operation

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM data WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM data WHERE Interaction_number=0)")
```

You do not need the double equal in your test, and do not use `data$ID` and such to refer to the data columns in the SQL expression (you can use `data.ID` but it is unnecessary to use the dataframe name in this case).

It may be helpful to read up on SQL before using this function much.  Keep in mind that what it will do is turn all your referenced dataframes into tables using the same name as the dataframe, and all of the columns into fields using the same name as the columns.  Thus in this case, we are querying a table named *data* with fields named *ID*, *Interaction*, and *Interaction_number*.

Comment: I already have used this as I mentioned in the question and got the following error: Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: data$ID

Comment: What error?  You only said that "the function didn't work".  In what way didn't it work.  The above works perfectly for me.  Make sure that you have used the expression that I did - it is different from yours.

Comment: @BitanshuDas Look at where my command is different from yours, and notice that I did not use `data$ID`, only `ID`.  That is where that error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. It does work when we exclude the $ table name part.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `dplyr`.  Group the 'data' by 'ID', and `filter` if there is `any` 0 values in the 'Interaction_number'.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(any(!Interaction_number))
#      ID Interaction Interaction_number
#    (int)       (chr)              (int)
#1     1         abc                  1
#2     1         xyz                  2
#3     1         pqr                  3
#4     1         ced                  0
#5     2          ab                  0
#6     2         efg                  1
#7     3        asdf                  2
#8     3         fgh                  3
#9     3         abc                  0
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, ave(!Interaction_number, ID, FUN=any)),]
```

Or this can be done without any group by

```
df1[df1$ID %in%subset(df1, !Interaction_number)$ID,]
```